# What is the best way to do this string transformation in shell?

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sh

I am trying to write a shell script that will need to transform input of the following form:

```
foo/bar/baz/qux.txt
bar/baz/quz.txt
baz/quz/foo.txt
```

Into:

```
baz-qux
quz
foo
```

I.e. split on '/', drop the first 2 segments, drop the '.txt' and substitute remaining slashes for hyphens.

The substitution seems straightforward enough using tr:

```
paths=$(cat <<- EOF
foo/bar/baz/qux.txt
bar/baz/quz.txt
baz/quz/foo.txt
EOF
)

echo $paths | tr '/' '-' | tr '.txt' ' '
```

I've tried various forms of

```
cut -d '/' -f x
```

To get the necessary segments but am coming up short.

I'm a ruby guy so tempted to reach for my hammer and just use ruby:

```
lines.each { |s| s.split('/')[2..-1].join('-').split('.')[0] }
```

But deploying ruby for this one operation seems like it might be overkill. And I would like to improve my shell skills anyway so was wondering if there is a more elegant way anyone would recommend to do this in shell?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The command `tr '.txt' ' '` does *not* do what you want -- it doesn't delete the ".txt", it converts it to 4 spaces, and it also does the same to any other "t", "x", and "." in the name. For example, "test1.txt" -> " es 1    ".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done using `bash` [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
for name in foo/bar/baz/qux.txt bar/baz/quz.txt baz/quz/foo.txt; do
    new=${name#*/}   # drop the shortest prefix match for */, thus everything up to first /
    new=${new#*/}    # repeat, dropping the second segment
    new=${new%.txt}  # drop shortest suffix match for .txt
    new=${new//\//-} # convert any remaining slashes
    echo "$new"
done
```

Gives:

```
baz-qux
quz
foo
```

These are all `bash` shell built-in constructs, so no external processes like `cut`, `sed` or `tr` required.

Comment: Would you accept an edit that moved the comments to inline form, to prevent the code from *looking* longer than it is?

Comment: Of course @CharlesDuffy.  I had considered putting the meat into a function, which I would probably do if the code was for me.

Comment: Given the first line of sample input, I think `new=${name##*/};new=${new%.txt}` would be all that is required? Good luck to all.

Comment: Feeling dense - not seeing where the last remaining `/` is being changed to `-`.

Comment: @PaulHodges the guy who edited probably missed this line:     new=${new//\//-}
I copied it for local test in the first version of the post

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `new=${name#*/*/}` instead of two expansions?

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything in one `sed` command

```
sed -E 's|([^/]*/){,2}||; s|/|-|g; s|\.txt$||' file
```

Replace `\.txt$` with `\.[^.]*$` to remove all extensions instead of only `.txt`.

Comment: This is going to be the better approach if processing a huge number of inputs in one run (enough to overcome the constant-time startup costs of `sed` with its faster I/O once running), or cdarke's if it's a smaller number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this: `cut -d/ -f3- | cut -d. -f1 | tr / -`

Explanation:

- `cut -d/ -f3-` - split on '/', and keep the third field and everything after it (`baz/qux.txt`)
- `cut -d. -f1` - split on '.', keep the first value (drops the file extension) (`baz/qux`)
- `tr / -` - Transform any remaining '/' into '-'.
  (`baz-qux`)

Comment: Conceptually simple, but spinning up three separate processes is quite a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl

```
$ cat mark_smith.txt
foo/bar/baz/qux.txt
bar/baz/quz.txt
baz/quz/foo.txt

$ perl -F"/" -lane ' @a=@F[2..$#F]; @b=map{s/.txt//g;$_} @a; print join("-",@b) ' mark_smith.txt
baz-qux
quz
foo

$
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming `.` is only in the filenames

```
$ awk -F[/.] '{n=NF; p=$(n-1)} n>4{p=$(n-2)"-"p} {print p}' file

baz-qux
quz
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/^.{8}|.txt$/,"")sub(/\//,"-")}1' file

baz-qux
quz
foo
```